# Special case of graph-theory cycle

Tags: graph-theory

In graph theory, is there a name for a (simple) cycle with no path between any of its non-adjacent vertices? When the graph is planar, this could be called a face, but how about non-planar graphs?

Comment: Isn't such a graph made of the union of some $K_i$'s ? Am I making a wrong move somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean that there is no *edge* between *non-consecutive* vertices of the cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're talking about a [chordless cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)#Chordless_cycles), or sometimes an induced cycle.

A face in a planar graph doesn't necessarily conform to this so there is some conflict in your description.

Comment: You might also possibly be talking about the cycles on a [cactus graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus_graph)